# "APPLICATION_DOES_NOT_EXIST" from Mobile first server in ionic 4 mfp application

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, ionic4, worklight-server

when i launch the ionic mobile application we are checking with mfp it is giving below error not able to launch application in some times.
please find the response json from mfp
[ibm-mobilefirst] worklight
responseJSON
:
errorCode
:
**"APPLICATION_DOES_NOT_EXIST"**
errorMsg
:
"Application doesn't exist"
[[Prototype]]
:
Object
responseText
:
"{"errorCode":"APPLICATION_DOES_NOT_EXIST","errorMsg":"Application doesn't exist"}"
status
:
403
statusText
:
"Forbidden"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51ng0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will see this error "APPLICATION_DOES_NOT_EXIST" when your application is not registered in the mobilefirst server console.

In root of you app run command > mfpdev app register

More details see here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/mpf/8.0.0?topic=server-mobilefirst-platform-cli-registering-cordova-applications